# Identify user's high score ranking in Parse back-end

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have developed a simple Swift iOS game with high scores stored in Parse. Saving and retrieving data works fine. What I'd like to do now is to implement a "user ranking" -feature, which would show how the user's high score ranks against other players. In practice this would mean that I'd need:

- The total count of high scores in Parse
- The ranking of the user's high score on that list

If Parse did not have any query limits, this would be relatively easy to implement for even a newbie coder like myself. However, it does, and I just can't figure out how to implement this in a way that this would still work (1) efficiently, and (2) even if there were e.g., 100,000 high scores.

What would be a workable way of identifying the current user's ranking amongst all other high scores stored in Parse? I don't want to use countObjects as I believe it fails when the number of objects gets high.

Comment: I don't think countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() fails to easily... Have you really had experience with it breaking? Because I feel you could easily accomplish what you want to do here by nesting this call twice with an equal or greater than called on top of it. Have you thought of that/does that make sense? I'll post some sample code as an answer for you to have just in case.

Comment: Isn't countObjects limited to 1,000 as well? Or have I misunderstood? If the limit is there, then it would seem to me that there's a high chance of it breaking if I need to circumventing that limit.

Answer (score 0):

Were you using the `countObjectsInBackground` without a completion block? Because then I'd believe that you could get messed up with asynchronous issues, but it's very easy, and very safe with the `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method.

```
func getUserPosition() {
        let totalQuery = PFQuery(className: "highScores")
        totalQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (number, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                //your total number is the number var passed here
                let positionQuery = PFQuery(className: "highScores")
                positionQuery.whereKey("score", greaterThanOrEqualTo: userHighScore)
                positionQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (position, error) -> Void in
                    //your user's position is the position var passed here
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if you saw the comments above. Would this not break if there are more than a 1000 objects or am I misunderstanding how this works? See https://www.parse.com/questions/issue-with-using-countobjects-on-class-with-large-number-of-objects-millions UPDATE: Looks like a count query might not have that limit, but can get very slow if there are a lot of entries.